# ros2 rviz Fixed Frame [map] does not exist" appears in the global status. How can I solve this?

Tags: navigation, ros2, rviz

I was trying the navigation2 tutorial on ros2.
Install the ROS 2 binary package as described in the official documentation.
Install the Nav2 package using your operating system's package manager.

sudo apt install ros--navigation2
sudo apt install ros--nav2-bringup
Install the Turtlebot 3 package (Humble and earlier).

sudo apt install ros--turtlebot3-gazebo

Running the sample¶

Launch Terminal with GUI
Set key environment variables.

Source /opt/ros//setup.bash
Export TURTLEBOT3_MODEL=Waffle
import GAZEBO_MODEL_PATH=$GAZEBO_MODEL_PATH:/opt/ros//share/turtlebot3_gazebo/models

In the same terminal run:

ros2 launch nav2_bringup tb3_simulation_launch.py ​​headless:=False
I open rviz in this way, but the error "For frame [ ]: Fixed Frame [map] does not exist" appears in the global status. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things may be missing:
You have to localize the robot with an intial position. For this click the Green arrwow for pose estimate in RVIZ and place it on the map.
Second, maybe your are viewing the wrong frame in RVIZ, the world_frame has to be "map".

Answer (score 1):

you need click "2D Pose Estimate" to initialize the position.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/paUiR.png)